# Failing to boot when /etc/X11/xorg.conf [device] driver="nvidia"

Tags: xorg, nvidia, multi-monitor

BTW I am using Arch, have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile, KDE with SDDM, laptop with internal screen and 2 external connected by USB-C.

Everything worked fine. Yesterday I did a full upgrade. Today the graphical boot failed, Playmouth Boot Screen could not be terminated.

I played around and found that the graphics will boot when I comment this line in **/etc/X11/xorg.conf**:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 530.41.03

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
.....
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
#    Driver         "nvidia"             #when commented graphical boot works with 1 Monitor
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection
.....
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

So I guess that it is related to the NVIDIA driver

```
pacman -Q nvidia
nvidia 530.41.03-6     #different from mod. normal?
```

When I check the mod loaded:

```
modinfo $(modprobe --resolve-alias nvidia) 
filename:       /lib/modules/6.2.13-arch1-1/extramodules/nvidia.ko.xz
firmware:       nvidia/530.41.03/gsp_tu10x.bin
firmware:       nvidia/530.41.03/gsp_ga10x.bin   #different from above. normal?
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        530.41.03
supported:      external
...
```

Kernel log. I've noticed that some signature fails to load but no idea if this is the problem and if how to fix it:
dmesg | grep nvidia

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=2efc41cd-9bc2-430d-ad4c-9119cfc5c554 rw loglevel=3 quiet nvidia-drm.modeset=1
[    0.028531] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=2efc41cd-9bc2-430d-ad4c-9119cfc5c554 rw loglevel=3 quiet nvidia-drm.modeset=1
[    3.136458] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.695298] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.695323] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    3.709474] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    3.902894] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 510
[    3.903724] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    3.903860] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    4.014272] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[    4.108731] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 508.
[    4.306861] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[    4.360489] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  530.41.03  Thu Mar 16 19:23:04 UTC 2023
[    4.364399] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    5.028945] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
```

The problem is that I need the Nvidia driver for my external usbc screens. They are not working anymore for some unknown reason and I don't know how to proceed debugging.
I am relative new in Linux. Any ideas how to continue?

**UPDATE**
When I try to start the Boot screen from login shell i get this error:

```
kstart plasma-desktop
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

**I've tried:**
Reinstalling: qt, nvidia related packages, plasma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2097245#p2097245

Deleting (with backup) of

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf
```

solved my problem